# What is the naming convention of view folder for CamelCase type controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a controller named: `CustomAuthController`. Now I want to create a folder for this controller. What should I choose for this folder name. I mean what name is the best practice for laravel. is `custom_auth` is best pick. Is there any rule?

Comment: Looking how when installing Laravel the directories are created inside `/app`, I think it follows the same logic of namespaces `\<NamespaceName>(\<SubNamespaceNames>)*\<ClassName>`. I have not found specifically for the Controllers directories, but you can take a look at the [PSR-4 standards](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

View folders in Laravel are made to help the structure of the front end of the app. It has nothing to do with what Controller you use to provide functionality for it.

For instance, you can have the `layouts` folder where you put all your blades which can be used into another blade as a reusable section. The views under `layouts` folder might also use your `CustomAuthController` controller. Does that make sense?

Name your view folders in a way which helps you understand the front end structure of your website.

As for the naming convention, always try to keep it one word, all small case and usually a plural word as it holds a group of blade views.

If you need to make it as two words, mostly `snake_case` is used but there is no written rule about it.